# Featured or last post with a different WordPress style without plugin

Tags: php

How do I get a highlight with only one category but with a different style for each ?

Exemple: [image]

My Code is:

```
<?php
                      $args=array(
                      'cat' => 2,
                      'orderby' => 'date',
                      'order' => 'DESC',
                      'post_type' => 'post',
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
                      'posts_per_page' => 3,
                      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                      );
                      $my_query = null;
                      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

                      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
                      <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'larger' ); ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                            <div class="single-services mb-80">
                                <div class="services-thumb mb-35">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="img">
                                </div>
                                <div class="services-content">
                                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <?php  endwhile; ?>
                      <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking.

Comment: @TonyDjukic I would like to show a list of the last posts with only one category but with different layouts like the example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gM7Z.png

Answer (score 2):

The concept is that you have queried WP for a defined number of posts, so you can presume you have a total or 3 posts returned thanks to `'posts_per_page' => 3,`-- remember, this might not be true, is there are not enough posts or other parts of the query reduce this number, perhaps because of the wrong category ID.

Here is some pseudo-code to show how you can affect the markup used for each post you render, using the loop ( the rest of your code would still be required ):

```php
// track post loops ##
$loop = 0;

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
    switch( $loop ) {
        case 0: // $loop = 0
?>
    <h4>Loop One:<?php the_title(); ?></h4>     
<?php  
        break;

        case 1: // $loop == 1 etc..
        default: // works for all other values not defined in switch cases..
?>
    <h4>Loop Two:<?php the_title(); ?></h4>     
<?php  
        break;
    }

// iterate post loop count ##
$loop ++;

endwhile;
```

Comment: How can I put the category that will show in your code? I'm still an apprentice ....

Comment: Look at this function - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/